# SwiftUI number of lines for Text element causing random margin behavior

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, margins

I'm having a bit of trouble with this particular view. For some reason, it seems like depending on whether the Text(title) element is one line or two lines, I'm getting very odd behavior for the total height of the view. All the elements are dynamically populated so I can't just have a set height. I've ruled out that this is issue not dependent on the image that's loaded, but always occurs when the Text(title) element is one line. As you can see, when the element is only one line, it causes the image to have a padding above it and the 'See more' button to have a padding below it. The first image shows the margin issue (single line for title) and the second shows how the margins aren't there for multi-line title. Any help much appreciated!

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/MB6Dt.jpg
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDKOj.jpg

   ```
      VStack(alignment: .leading) {
          Image(systemName: "camera")
              .data(url: URL(string: picture)!)
              .resizable()
              .scaledToFill()
              .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8)
              .maxHeight(215)
              .clipped()
          Group {
              HStack {
                  Text(title)
                      .bold()
                      .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                      .padding(.vertical, 5)
                  Spacer()
              }
              HStack {
                  Text(subInformation)
                      .font(.system(size: 17, weight: .semibold))
                      .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                      .padding(.bottom, 5)
                  Spacer()
              }
              HStack {
                  Text(description)
                      .padding(.bottom, 2)
                      .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                  Spacer()
              }
          }.padding(.horizontal)
          DestinationAd()
              .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8, height: 50)
              .padding(.bottom, 5)
          Link(destination: URL(string: urlToOpen)!, label: {
              HStack {
                  Spacer()
                  Text("See more")
                      .padding(.vertical, 5)
                  Spacer()
              }.background(Color.blue)
              .cornerRadius(10)
          }).padding(.horizontal, 10)
          .padding(.bottom, 10)
      }.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.8)
      .background(Color.white)
      .cornerRadius(20)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think that everything works as expected in your example. You are populating VStack with some child elements. VStack wraps it's content by default. In the first case (when the text only has one line) child views take less space that in the second example.

If you don't want to set `frame` for your `VStack`, maybe `Spacer` after the image and before the button could help.

Comment: I only cared about having the width of the Stack as 80% of screen width. I set the frame of the VStack so the height should automatically be JUST large enough to contain all of the stuff inside the stack, right (with no margin between image and top of vstack and bottom of 'See more' and bottom of vstack)? So why would there be extra padding above the image and below the 'See more' button? It's not like I hard coded height of VStack--it should shrink with smaller child elements.

Comment: And when I add the spacers, it just makes the VStack bigger by pushing the elements to the very top/bottom of the safe area of the phone screen, which isn't what I want. I need it to be as small vertically as possible, not larger.

Comment: Can you update the code and also add the code from the parent view? I will look into it.

Comment: Ok, I did not understand your question properly, but I think I understand now. I don't know why this is happening for you, but it works okay for me. Maybe the issue is in the parent code? Also your sample doesn't compile. You are using custom view modifiers. Can you provide minimalist code sample without custom views and modifiers where the issue persists?